# Testing classes in a C# console application

Tags: c#, class, parsing, datetime

**The following are requirements for a console application practice exercise. I have the classes built, I just can't figure out how to test them.**

You were recently hired by NU Bank as part of its growing development team.  Your first assignment is to design and build two classes that are to be utilized in both the banks website and internal applications.  The first is a loan class representing a loan contract. The second is a customer class representing the individual receiving the loan.  The requirements for each class are as follows:
1.  Each class must have at least 2 members and 2 methods.
2.  The customer class must store the customer’s name, phone number, and date of birth at a minimum.
3.  The loan class must store the contract number, date of execution, and the associated customer at a minimum.
4.  When assigning the customer object into the loan object, the customer must be at least 21 yrs old.  If the customer is under 21, then the assignment must be rejected.

For purposes of testing, you will write a small console application.  Gather any information needed to populate the objects via the console.  The output of the application must show the contents of each object and indicate whether or not the assignment of the customer to the loan was successful.

**Here is what I have so far...**

**Loan class**

```
    class Loan
{
    private int contractNumber;
    private DateTime doe;
    private double loanAmt;

    public int ContractNumber
    {
        get
        {
            return contractNumber;
        }
        set
        {
            contractNumber = value;
        }
    }

    public double LoanAmt
    {
        get 
        { 
            return loanAmt; 
        }
        set 
        { 
            loanAmt = value; 
        }
    }

    public Loan()
    {
        doe = DateTime.Now;
        loanAmt = 0.00;
    }

    public Loan(DateTime doe, double loanAmt)
    {
        doe = DateTime.Now;
        loanAmt = LoanAmt;
    }
}
```

**And Customer class**

```
     class Customer
{
    private string firstName;
    private string lastName;
    private DateTime dob;
    private long phoneNumber;

    public string FirstName
    {
        get
        {
            return firstName;
        }
        set
        {
            firstName = value;
        }
    }

    public string LastName
    {
        get
        {
            return lastName;
        }
        set
        {
            lastName = value;
        }
    }

    public DateTime DoB
    {
        get
        {
            return dob.Date;
        }
        set
        {
            dob = value;
        }
    }

    public long PhoneNumber
    {
        get
        {
            return phoneNumber;
        }
        set
        {
            phoneNumber = value;
        }
    }

    public Customer()
    {
        DateTime defaultDate = new DateTime(1991, 04, 29);
        firstName = "Enter first name here.";
        lastName = "Enter last name here.";
        dob = Convert.ToDateTime("04/30/1991");
        phoneNumber = 1234567890;
    }

    public Customer(string firstName, string lastName, DateTime dob, long phoneNumber)
    {
        firstName = FirstName;
        lastName = LastName;
        dob = DoB;
        phoneNumber = PhoneNumber;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Simple error, DateTime is constructed like so:

`DateTime defaultDate = new DateTime(1991, 04, 29);`

Not:

`DateTime defaultDate = new DateTime(1991 / 04 / 29);`

Otherwise what you've done so far looks fine. You just need to have a driver now using `Console.ReadLine()` to get input, parse it and create your objects while testing the constraints.

Comment: Thank you for your help, but I'm a very poor coder and I'm afraid I need much more help than this...

Comment: I'm afraid that's the only question you've asked (re: your DateTime error) and this is a Question & Answer site.